# Sort Two Lists with relationship

Tags: c#, list, sorting

As I can sort two lists or two vectors, ie I sort a list (distances) and according to her order as I ordered another list that keeps me indexes.
Thanks.

Pd. I'm working on Net framework 2.0

```
List1          List2
[0]=125        [0]=1
[1]=130        [1]=2
[2]=124        [2]=3
[3]=128        [3]=4
```

After Sorting List1 i want this

```
List1          List2
[0]=124        [0]=3
[1]=125        [1]=1
[2]=128        [2]=4
[3]=130        [3]=2
```

Pd. My list has 2000 records...

as I can do? thks..

Comment: Hi Nicole77, in order to get the best possible answer, it would be helpful if you could post some code of what you have tried so far, and, additionally a small sample of what the data would look like to help make the answers as specific as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<decimal> scores = GetScores();
List<Fruit> fruit = GetFruit();

List<Tuple<decimal, Fruit>> sortedPairs = scores
  .Zip(fruit, (s, f) => Tuple.Create(s, f))
  .OrderBy(x => x.Item1)
  .ToList();

scores = sortedPairs.Select(x => x.Item1).ToList();
fruit = sortedPairs.Select(x => x.Item2).ToList();
```

Now all you have to do is implement Zip, OrderBy, Select, ToList and Tuple.

Comment: @Nicole777 accept the answer if that's what you were looking for. it's  a good way of showing your appreciation to the person answering your question.